# Rails 5.1 nested service folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service

Rails 5.1.3
Ruby 2.2.5
Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

Closer to the madness. I have services folder in my app. it contains another folder like 'users'...so for example 'app/services/users/AuthenticationService.rb'.

Currently I have modules and main goal is for controller usage.

```
AuthenticationService.call params[:email], params[:password]
```

Is worth to mention that this doesn't work too

```
auth = Services::Users::AuthenticationService.call params[:email], params[:password]
```

This is the service code:

```
module Services
  module Users
    module AuthenticationService
      class << self
        def call(email, password)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Rails return this exception:

```
#<NameError: uninitialized constant AuthenticationController::Services>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name the file `app/services/users/authentication_service.rb` and the service shall be `Users::AuthenticationService`, it should work by itself ;-)

The service should be something like:

```
  module Users
    module AuthenticationService
      class << self
        def call(email, password)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Get rid of the outer `module Services`, to be able to use `Users::AuthenticationService` by itself

Comment: Thank you @Geoffroy but now I got this exception `#<LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Users::AuthenticationService, expected /Users/user/documents/projects/xyz/app/services/users/authentication_service.rb to define it>`

Comment: The file `app/services/users/authentication_service.rb` has to define `Users::AuthenticationService`, as expects rails, and apparently you did not define it. Maybe it's still defined inside `Services`, which you should remove.

Comment: @Geoffroy did you try the first call or the second one? it seems a problem that happens with the first call

Comment: @OscarRomero I updated my code to show what the service file should define. You should be rid of the `Services` module.

Comment: Thank you guys. I do as @Geoffroy says with the `::` prefix and is working. following Rails Guides [link] (https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#resolution-algorithm-for-qualified-constants)